# Referring to static member of a class result in "not a static member of class"

Tags: c++

I want to create a class were classes are derived from when they use a certain feature of the program that has to be initialized only once.
I created the class with a static bool member, and a default constructor. The default constructor checks the static member and runs the initialization if needed:

```
class WireUser {
public:
    static bool wireIntialized;
    WireUser::WireUser();
};

bool WireUser::wireInitialized = false;

WireUser::WireUser() {
    if (!wireInitialized) {
        Wire.begin();
        wireInitialized = true;
    }
};
```

When i try to compile this i get the following error:

> ```
>  error: 'bool WireUser::wireInitialized' is not a static member of 'class WireUser'
>  bool WireUser::wireInitialized = false;
> ```

If i remove the line were the member is initialized as false, the same errors occurs on the line containing `if (!wireInitialized) {`

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: A typo in `wireIntialized`, missing `i`.

Comment: oh My G.... this has to be the most stupid question here ever :-(. Thought I checked the spelling at least 10 times

Comment: [Some simple typos](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1cc09300905d811), fixed in my sample.

Comment: `WireUser::WireUser();` is also non-standard compliant. Use simply `WireUser();` inside the class declaration.

Comment: @Bascy many editors have the feature that if you highlight one instance of an identifier, the other instances of the same identifier will be outlined or emphasized in some way. Helps a lot with these things.

Comment: @Bascy The error and warning messages were pretty clear to come along with the necessary fixes.

Comment: @Bascy I extended my answer a bit regarding _thread safety_ considerations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of typos and small errors/warnings in your code (steps for fixing explained in the comments):

```
class WireUser {
public:
  static bool wireInitialized;
  WireUser(); // Don't use scope specifiers in declarations:  WireUser::WireUser();
};

bool WireUser::wireInitialized = false; // Typo fixed here 'wireInitialized' isn't the 
                                        // same as         'wireIntialized'

WireUser::WireUser() {
  if (!wireInitialized) {
    // Wire.begin(); Commented out because it's not in context of your question
    wireInitialized = true;
  }
} //; <<<< Omit the semicolon to get rid of the warning

int main (){
    WireUser wu;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53b32bf554a1d802).

---

Also you should consider to make that thread safe for initialization.
A `std::atomic<bool>` might be the right choice:

```
#include <atomic>

class WireUser {
public:
  static std::atomic<bool> wireInitialized;
  WireUser();
};

std::atomic<bool> WireUser::wireInitialized = {false};

WireUser::WireUser() {
  if (!wireInitialized.exchange(true)) {
    // Wire.begin();
    // wireInitialized = true;
  }
}

int main (){
    WireUser wu;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eca4bec6be009d54)

Comment: Shouldn't the `wireInitialized` check be `if (!wireInitialized.exchange(true)){...}`? Right now, multiple threads can enter the if block before one thread successfully sets `wireInitialized` to true, though I suppose that sacrifices exception safety in the event `Wire::begin` isn't `noexcept`...

Comment: @jaggedSpire THX for the hint. I adopted it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on thread-safety but being thread safe is totally no issue here as this is used in a Arduino board which is not multithreaded